# blocking wait() on boost timer

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

[The documentation says](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_waitable_timer/wait/overload1.html):

> This function is used to wait for the timer to expire. This function blocks and does not return until the timer has expired.

Does this block the whole I/O processing similar to a sleep or does the asynchronous I/O still work? In other words: If I have asynchronous I/O or other timers running on the same io_service, do they block until the `wait` is over, or do they get called while the process is `wait`ing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thread that you call `wait` on will be blocked but if you have other threads they should continue executing.

Note that if you are using strands then if you call `wait` from within a strand no other executors will run for that strand even if other threads are available.

Comment: Thanks. I had hoped for a co-routine like behavior were wait is similar to a yield  and the io_service is handling other tasks while one handler is waiting. Too bad...

Comment: No, if you want co-routine behaviour you have to use co-routines

Comment: Are there co-routines that use the boost::asio io_service as a scheduler?

Comment: yes: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/core/coroutine.html

Comment: or: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/spawn.html

Comment: Thanks. That seems to be what I was looking for. I will see, whether I can wrap my mind around this.